# Can a citation be copied within Ancestry.com?

Tags: ancestry.com, citation

I created a source (a certain book) and citation (a certain page) within Ancestry.com and attached it to one person. The page mentions multiple people in my tree. Is there a way to duplicate the citation I created and attach it to a second person,  or do I have to copy and paste all of the information into a new citation? The only difference between the citations would be the associated facts and events.